# Big patches for memory dumps

Tags: ida

I am given a large memory dump (several megabytes). I need to update idb's memory. What I do now is: PatchQword(addr, value) if value != Qword(addr) for every qword in memory dump. Unfortunately, every PatchQword takes way too long (around 3-4 PatchQwords per second).

SO the question is: is there a way to tell IDA to update large regions of memory at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function in idc called LoadFile. It successfully does what I need.

Edit: there's also patch_many_bytes, but it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the value of original bytes, you can use put_bytes().

Comment: Currently on 6.95, because some important plugins aren't updated yet.